How to Draw a Diagram with a Custom Coordinate System and Shaded Areas?
I would like to draw the diagram shown below. Attached is my code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

% Rectangle
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);

% Forces (F0)
\draw[<-, red, thick] (1,1) -- (1,1.5) node[right] {$F_0$}; 
\draw[->, red, thick] (0,1) -- (-0.5,1) node[above] {$S_1$}; 
\draw[->, red, thick] (2,1) -- (2.5,1) node[above] {$F_0$}; 
\draw[->, red, thick] (2,1) -- (2,1.5) node[left] {$S_3$}; 
\draw[-, red] (2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[above] {}; 

% Rotational moment (aF0)
\draw[red, thick, ->] (1.2,0.5) arc[start angle=0, end angle=120, radius=0.2];
\node[red] at (1,0.5) {$aF_0$};


% Dimensions (a)
\draw[<->, red, thick] (0,-0.3) -- (1,-0.3) node[midway, above] {$a$};
\draw[<->,red, thick] (1,-0.3) -- (2,-0.3) node[midway, above] {$a$};
\draw[<->,red, thick] (2.3,0) -- (2.3,1) node[midway, right] {$a$};

\draw[->, red, thick] (1,0) -- (1,-0.6) node[right] {$S_2$}; 
\draw[<-, red, thick] (2,0) -- (2,-0.6) node[above right] {$F_0$}; 



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I am unsure how to draw elements such as the coordinate system with the plus symbol and the arrow in the bottom left corner, or the three shaded areas.

Could you please help me?
Thank you very much!

Here is an other way to do it.

1. General consideration
Though you can define all coordinates in absolute terms, e.g. from picking them from a manual drawing, I'd use a \node for the rectangle. As you will see, it's easier (after you've got used to it) to specify coordinates related to the rectangle.
Keep in mind, that Tikz commands, like \draw, in fact creates paths. Think of them as a series of actions to be performed, just like in a movie scene:

start the path with \
end it with ;
and put node, coordinate etc. as needed in between (i.e, without \)

2. tikzlibraries needed here

modify arrow tips
draw hatch pattern
draw this angle like in triangles

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns,angles,quotes}

3. tikzpicture

the scale is not needed with class standalone, and especially bad here
define styles as needed, e.g. to simplify and unify code

\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5] % not needed with standalone
[
    >={Stealth},    % looks better to me
    wall/.style ={pattern=north east lines,minimum width=10mm},
    wallh/.style={pattern=north east lines,minimum height=10mm},
    dot/.style={circle,draw=black, fill=black,inner sep=1pt},
]

4. rectangle as node

draw its outer shape (default IS rectangle) of an empty node
size it via the 3 parameters shown
inner sep could be ignored, but it puts some extra margin around the (empty) text
KEY: you can and will reference this node via its name (R) frequently below

% Rectangle
%\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\node[draw,
      minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm,
      inner sep=0pt,
      fill=black!10] (R) at (0,0) {};

5. Forces
Examples:

referring to node (R)
start at its middle top (R.north)
do some relative drawing, where \fln is defied as a constant, above
put a node BEFORE the end point
anchor it west, so it appears to be aligned right of the arrow

\draw[red,<-] (R.north)      -- node[anchor=west ]{$F_0$} ++(0,\fln);

More complex path:

same idea as above
shift label S2 a bit along the line drawn [pos=.7]
remember end point as (A2) to draw the wall anchors, later

\draw[red,->] (R.south)      -- node[anchor=west,pos=.7]{$S_2$} % shift label
                                 ++(0,-1)  coordinate(A2);

6. Wall anchors

draw a node with empty text, put hatch pattern (see style wall)
use [anchor=south] to put it where the S3 arrow ends
draw a solid line fromlower left to lower right

% ~~~ Anchors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\node[anchor=south,wall] (W3) at (A3) {};
\draw (W3.south west) -- (W3.south east);

7. rotational element

move first to the starting point of the arc, related to (R), i.e. its center
then draw the arc
put node text at (R), but shift a bit for better optics

% Rotational moment (aF0)
\draw[red, thick, ->] (R) +(0,-.5) arc[start angle=-120, end angle=120, radius=0.5];
\node[red,yshift=-1mm] at (R) {$a \times F_0$};

8. help lines and dimensions

I used a different color
drawing two lines should be evident
dimension arrows span between two node edges, shifted
text node anchored as needed

% ~~~ help lines ~~~~~~~~
\draw[magenta] (R.south east) -- +(.6,0);
\draw[magenta] (R.south west) -- +(0,-.6);


% ~~~ dimensions ~~~~~~~~
\draw[magenta,<->] ([xshift=3mm]R.north east) -- 
                                node[anchor=west]{$a$} 
                                ([xshift=3mm]R.south east);

9. dots, if you like
I put just 2 as demo. As you can see you should either draw them before the red arrows, so they don't hide the red end point, OR shift the Wall-points a little, so the arrow ends at the dot.
% ~~~ dots ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\node[dot] at (R.south){}; 
\node[dot] at (W2.north){}; 

10. coordinate system

just draw between 3 points, shifted
remember cooridnates X, Y and Z (origin)
use \pic ... {angle= }; as shown
if you want a plus in math mode, you need the quotes library, see above

% ~~~ Coordinate system ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\draw[<->] (R.south west) ++(-.5,0) coordinate(X) 
                -- ++(-.9,0) coordinate(Z)
                 -- ++(0,.9) coordinate(Y);

\node[anchor=north,yshift=-1mm] at (X) {x};
\node[anchor=east ]             at (Y) {y};

\pic["$+$",draw,->,teal] {angle=X--Z--Y};

11. final suggestion
Identify more options you can define as styles and move&replace the as shown. It will make your code more read-able, less error prone.
You may want to define mor constants for the varios lengths used.

\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{amsmath}                   % not used here
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns,angles,quotes}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\fln[0]{0.8} % force length
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5] % not needed with standalone
[
    >={Stealth},    % looks better to me
    wall/.style ={pattern=north east lines,minimum width=10mm},
    wallh/.style={pattern=north east lines,minimum height=10mm},
    dot/.style={circle,draw=black, fill=black,inner sep=1pt},
]

% Rectangle
%\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\node[draw,
      minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm,
      inner sep=0pt,
      fill=black!10] (R) at (0,0) {};

% ~~~ Forces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\draw[red,<-] (R.north)      -- node[anchor=west ]{$F_0$} ++(0,\fln);
\draw[red,->] (R.north east) -- node[anchor=south]{$F_0$} ++(\fln,0);
\draw[red,<-] (R.south east) -- node[anchor=west ]{$F_0$} ++(0,-\fln);

\draw[red,->] (R.north west) -- node[anchor=south]{$S_1$} ++(-.6,0) coordinate(A1);
\draw[red,->] (R.south)      -- node[anchor=west,pos=.7]{$S_2$} % shift label
                                 ++(0,-1)  coordinate(A2);
\draw[red,->] (R.north east) -- node[anchor=east ]{$S_3$} ++(0,1.3) coordinate(A3);

% ~~~ Anchors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\node[anchor=south,wall] (W3) at (A3) {};
\draw (W3.south west) -- (W3.south east);

\node[anchor=north,wall] (W2) at (A2) {};
\draw (W2.north west) -- (W2.north east);

\node[anchor=east,wallh] (W1) at (A1) {};
\draw (W1.north east) -- (W1.south east);


% Rotational moment (aF0)
\draw[red, thick, ->] (R) +(0,-.5) arc[start angle=-120, end angle=120, radius=0.5];
\node[red,yshift=-1mm] at (R) {$a \times F_0$};

% ~~~ help lines ~~~~~~~~
\draw[magenta] (R.south east) -- +(.6,0);
\draw[magenta] (R.south west) -- +(0,-.6);


% ~~~ dimensions ~~~~~~~~
\draw[magenta,<->] ([xshift=3mm]R.north east) -- 
                                node[anchor=west]{$a$} 
                                ([xshift=3mm]R.south east);
                                
\draw[magenta,<->] ([yshift=-3mm]R.south west) -- 
                                node[anchor=north]{$a$} 
                                ([yshift=-3mm]R.south);
                                
\draw[magenta,<->] ([yshift=-3mm]R.south) -- 
                                node[anchor=north]{$a$} 
                                ([yshift=-3mm]R.south east);


% ~~~ dots ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\node[dot] at (R.south){}; 
\node[dot] at (W2.north){}; 

% ~~~ Coordinate system ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\draw[<->] (R.south west) ++(-.5,0) coordinate(X) 
                -- ++(-.9,0) coordinate(Z)
                 -- ++(0,.9) coordinate(Y);

\node[anchor=north,yshift=-1mm] at (X) {x};
\node[anchor=east ]             at (Y) {y};

\pic["$+$",draw,->,teal] {angle=X--Z--Y};



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You could optimise your code significantly by using styles and reusing coordinates. The following indicates how to do this, but full optimisation would require you to implement the strategies more fully.
The most efficient method would be to draw the shaded areas before the arrows etc. However, since you'd already done the latter, I used the backgrounds library so that these can be defined later but drawn first. I also added patterns.meta for the filling lines.
Note:

the use of hl, a style which makes the code simpler and more easily modified, if required;
the use of node (<name>) so nodes can be used later for positioning;
the insertion of coordinate (<name>) in paths for the same purpose.


\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,hl/.style={red,thick}]

  % Rectangle
  \draw[thick] (0,0) coordinate (o) rectangle (2,1) coordinate (tr) ;

  % Forces (F0)
  \draw[<-, hl] (1,1) -- (1,1.5) node[right] {$F_0$};
  \draw[->, hl] (0,1) -- (-0.5,1) node (s1) [above,midway] {$S_1$} coordinate (e1);
  \draw[->, hl] (2,1) -- (2.5,1) node[above] {$F_0$};
  \draw[->, hl] (2,1) -- (2,1.5) node (s3) [left, midway] {$S_3$} coordinate (e3);
  \draw[-, red] (2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[above] {};

  % Rotational moment (aF0)
  \draw[hl, ->] (1.2,0.5) arc[start angle=0, end angle=120, radius=0.2];
  \node[red] at (1,0.5) {$aF_0$};


  % Dimensions (a)
  \draw[<->, hl] (0,-0.3) -- (1,-0.3) node[midway, above] {$a$};
  \draw[<->,hl] (1,-0.3) -- (2,-0.3) node[midway, above] {$a$};
  \draw[<->,hl] (2.3,0) -- (2.3,1) node[midway, right] {$a$};

  \draw[->, hl] (1,0) -- (1,-0.6) coordinate (e2) node (s2) [right,anchor=south west,inner ysep=0pt] {$S_2$} ;
  \draw[<-, hl] (2,0) -- (2,-0.6) node[above right] {$F_0$};

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \path [thick,pattern={Lines[angle=45]}] (e3) ++(-0.125,0) coordinate (a) rectangle ++(.25,.1) coordinate (b) ;
    \draw [thick] (a) --  (b |- a) ;
    \path [thick,pattern={Lines[angle=45]}] (e2) ++(-0.125,0) coordinate (a) rectangle ++(.25,-.1) coordinate (b) ;
    \draw [thick] (a) --  (b |- a) ;
    \path [thick,pattern={Lines[angle=45]}] (e1) ++(0,-0.125) coordinate (a) rectangle ++(-.1,.25) coordinate (b) ;
    \draw [thick] (a) --  (b -| a) ;
  \end{scope}

  \draw [hl,<->] (o) ++(-2.5pt,0pt) node [below] {$x$} -- ++(-0.5,0) -- ++(0,0.5) node [left] {$y$};
  \draw [hl,->] (o) ++(-7pt,2.5pt) arc (0:90:0.25) node [midway,below left,inner sep=0pt] {$+$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Further notes:

I used deprecated syntax for arc and this should really be updated;
the positioning library and arrows.meta are recommended replacements for deprecated arrow tips and positioning syntax.


The syntax for the arc operation is named shorter syntax (cf. pgf manual). This syntax is not deprecated... this syntax is harder to read, so the normal syntax should be preferred in general.

@PaulGaborit well, I've been told I shouldn't use similar syntax for circle etc., so I suppose the same is true here. the trouble is, I can never remember the new (or long, if that's better) syntax ....
